# Riemann surface associated with complete analytic function of $(z^2-1)^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to define an analytic function on '$\mathbb{C}$' of the form $f(z)=(z^2-1)^{1/3}$, i.e. I first remove two semi-infinite rays $l_1$ and $l_2$, one going from $1$ to $\infty$ along the positive reals, one from $-1$ to $\infty$ along the negative reals, ending up with the domain $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus(l_1\cup l_2)$.

Then I have three choices for $f$, and they will differ by factors of $e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $e^{4\pi i/3}$. Since $U$ is simply-connected, such a function is well-defined after making the initial choice.

*First question:* This is pretty vague. How can I justify this?

*Second question:* If I now want to describe the Riemann surface associated with the complete analytic function of $(z^2-1)^{1/3}$, how can I do so using sort of a gluing procedure? I start with three copies of $U$, but how can I glue them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First question: On a simply connected domain $G$, every holomorphic function $f$ without zeros has a holomorphic logarithm, that is, there is a $g \in \mathscr{O}(G)$ with $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for all $z\in G$. For the logarithmic derivative of $f$ is holomorphic, and since $G$ is simply connected, it has a primitive $h$ on $G$. Then

$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(f(z)e^{-h(z)}\right) = f'(z)e^{-h(z)} - f(z)h'(z)e^{-h(z)} = e^{-h(z)}\left(f'(z) - f(z)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right) = 0,$$

so $f(z) = c\cdot e^{h(z)}$ with $c\neq 0$. Hence $g(z) = h(z)+\log c$ is - for every choice of $\log c$ - a holomorphic logarithm of $f$.

In our situation, the function $h(z) = z^2-1$ has no zeros in $U$, and therefore a holomorphic logarithm $g$. Then $e^{g(z)/3}$ is a branch of $\sqrt[3]{z^2-1}$ on $U$.

It is clear that if $f$ is a branch of $\sqrt[3]{z^2-1}$ on any domain then $g(z) = e^{2\pi i/3}f(z)$ and $h(z) = e^{4\pi i/3}f(z)$ define two other branches. Since every $w \neq 0$ has exactly three distinct cube roots, any branch of $\sqrt[3]{z^2-1}$ must agree with one of the three at a given point $z_0$ in the domain, and by continuity, in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. By the identity theorem, it must therefore be one of $f,g$ or $h$.

Second question: Let's call the three copies of $U$ by the names of $U_0,U_1$ and $U_2$. Let $f$ be the branch of $\sqrt[3]{z^2-1}$ on $U$ with $f(0) = -1$, and on $U_k$ choose the branch $f_k(z) = e^{2k\pi i/3}\cdot f(z)$.

Then we need to glue the $U_k$ together along the branch cuts, and we must determine which sheet must be glued to which along each cut. For that, we must find the argument of $f_k(z)$ as $z$ approaches the branch cuts from the upper respectively from the lower half-plane. On the sheet $U_0$, we have $f_0(it) < 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. As $z$ traverses a quarter-circle from the imaginary axis to a branch-cut, $z^2-1$ traverses a half-circle, and $\sqrt[3]{z^2-1}$ a third of a half-circle, that is, an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Thus the argument when approaching the branch-cut on the positive ray from the upper half-plane or the branch-cut on the negative ray from the lower half-plane ($f_0$ is an even function) is $\pi - \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{2\pi}{3}$. The argument when approaching the branch-cuts from the other half-plane is $\pi + \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{4\pi}{3}$. Writing the arguments in the order of quadrants, and noting that all arguments are increased by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ when going from one sheet to the next, we get

$$\begin{matrix}
U_0 & \frac{2\pi}{3} & \frac{4\pi}{3} & \frac{2\pi}{3} & \frac{4\pi}{3}\\
U_1 & \frac{4\pi}{3} & 0 & \frac{4\pi}{3} & 0\\
U_2 & 0 & \frac{2\pi}{3} & 0 & \frac{2\pi}{3}
\end{matrix}$$

so we must glue

1. the second quadrant of $U_0$ to the third quadrant of $U_1$,
2. the fourth quadrant of $U_1$ to the first quadrant of $U_2$,
3. the second quadrant of $U_2$ to the third quadrant of $U_0$,
4. the fourth quadrant of $U_0$ to the first quadrant of $U_1$,
5. the second quadrant of $U_1$ to the third quadrant of $U_2$,
6. the fourth quadrant of $U_2$ to the first quadrant of $U_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I just wondered, could you also argue as follows: Consider a very small circle around 1, call it $\gamma$. Then $\gamma^2-1$ will go around $0$ once and so $\sqrt[3]{\gamma^2-1}$ will be a third of a circle around $0$. Thus, when transversing the cut on the positive real line in counter-clockwise direction the argument changes by $2\pi/3$. Similarly for the other direction and for $-1$?

Comment: Yes, you can also use small circles around the branch points. The difference is that the semicircle connecting the two branch-cuts gives you the values at the upper edges of both branch-cuts and you infer the values on the lower edges from the parity of $f_0$, while the small circles give you the relation between the values on the upper and lower edges of one branch-cut, and you get the relation to the values at the other branch-cut from the parity (or otherwise). Not much of a difference. And of course for an algebraic function, you get a concrete realisation as a submanifold of $\Bbb C^2$

Comment: without gluing. Another way to get the surface without gluing is to consider the sheaf of germs of analytic functions and take the connected component of one germ. That is however again not very concrete.

Answer (score 2):

A more direct way, without any glueing, is to look directly at the locus $E$ of $y^3=z^2-1$ in $\mathbf C^2$. This equation defines a smooth affine curve, and the projection $(y,z) \mapsto z$ is locally an isomorphism away from the points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. Moreover this projection is generically three-sheeted. On $E$, the function $y$ satisfies $y^3=z^2-1$, i.e., morally $y$ 'is' $(z^2-1)^{1/3}$, and the function $y$ restricted to each "sheet" gives the three branches of your function.

Comment: That's also a good way of looking it. If you'd like to make it into a Riemann surface, could you just take charts $(y,z)\mapsto y$ around $(0,\pm 1)$?

Comment: @Fedra: Yes! It suffices to check that $y$ generates the maximal ideal of the local ring of $E$ at each of those points, since this implies that $y$ vanishes simply there. If you take $(0,1)$ for instance, then the maximal ideal is $(y,z-1)$; but since $z-1 = y^3/(z+1)$, and $z+1$ is a unit in this local ring (being nonvanishing at $(0,1)$), it follows that $z-1 \in (y)$, so the ideal is principal, generated by $(y)$.